# The analog of the "~*" operator in HQL

Tags: java, regex, postgresql, hibernate, hql

SQL query: `select * from users where phone ~* '61'`

How can this be expressed in HQL?

Answer (score 1):

HQL doesn't have support for `~` (tilde) operator.